# Is it possible to use mint4win and wubi at the same time?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, mint

A year or two ago, I installed mint4win on a Windows 7 netbook, and have used it frequently since, with no issues (even once when I had to cold reboot!). I enjoy using Linux Mint, but after trying Ubuntu 12.04 from a USB stick, I'd like to be able to install that, too. The problem is that I share the Windows 7 netbook with my family, and I have to be careful not to mess up Windows, which is why I went the mint4win route in the first place.

So, here's the question: is it possible to install Precise using wubi while still keeping Mint, using mint4win?

Answer (score 1):

If mint4win uses `wubildr.mbr` and `wubildr` to boot (which I believe it does), then it's not possible to install and use both (without some manual linking i.e. through a custom grub entry). The `wubildr` file is hardcoded to look for `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` with Wubi, and for mint4win I assume it's `\linuxmint\disks\root.disk`. So you'd have to switch `wubildr` to boot different versions (even if you had two entries in the windows boot manager it would always boot one of either Mint or Ubuntu - the one you installed last).

There may also be conflicts in the registry entries (but this seems more likely to be separate due to the different installer name, so not a problem).

So to explain how Wubi/Mint4win boots:

1. Windows boot manager calls `wubildr.mbr`. This can be within `\linuxmint\winboot` or `\ubuntu\winboot` for Win7/Vista (or in `C:\` for XP).
2. `wubildr.mbr` searches all partitions for the first `wubildr` it finds. This is always in the root of the partition (so can be only one).
3. `wubildr` is hardcoded to look for either `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` (for Ubuntu) or `\linuxmint\disks\root.disk` (for Mint).

In theory, assuming there are no other conflicts, you could install both Wubi and Mint4Win, but it will always boot the most recently installed. You could then add a custom grub boot entry to boot the other install. But this sort of thing isn't usual for the typical Wubi/Mint4Win user.